# How to print the subdirectory name using python

Tags: python, list, os.walk

My code scans the directories and sub directories under the 'Monitors' folder, but somehow I failed to print the sub directory names.

Monitors is the parent directory and Dell is sub directory and io are the files under Dell.

```
-Monitors
-------- Cab.txt
--- Dell
-------- io.txt
-------- io2.txt
```

My parent directory and code

```
parent_dir = 'E:\Logs\Monitors'

def files(parent_dir):
    for file in os.listdir(parent_dir):
      if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(parent_dir, file)):
        yield file

def created(file_path):
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        file_created =  time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(os.path.getctime(file_path)))
        return file_created


len = (item for item in files(parent_dir))
str = ""
for item in len:
    str +="File Name: " + os.path.join('E:\\Logs\\Monitors\\', item) + "\n" \
    + "File Created on: " + created(os.path.join('E:\\Logs\\Monitors\\', item)) + "\n" \
print str;
```

Output

```
E:Logs\Monitors\Cab.txt
E:Logs\Monitors\io.txt
E:Logs\Monitors\io2.txt
```

My Desired Output

```
E:Logs\Monitors\Cab.txt
E:Logs\Monitors\Dell\io.txt
E:Logs\Monitors\Dell\io2.txt
```

I tried using the variable in path.join but ended with errors.

Comment: You can't actually get that output, unless `io.txt` and `io2.txt` live in `E:\Logs\Monitors` directly. You never produce files from `Dell`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then is there any other way to list all the files in the directory and its sub directory with path names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use `os.listdir()`, use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to traverse all directories in a tree:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(parent_dir):
    for filename in filenames:
        full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        print 'File Name: {}\nFile Created on: {}\n'.format(
            full_path, created(full_path))
```

Each iteration over `os.walk()` gives you information about one directory. `dirpath` is the full path to that directory, and `dirnames` and `filenames` are lists of directory and filenames in that location. Simply use a loop over the filenames to process each.